# Can a non distinct ordered pair in a relation R, belong to its power RR

Tags: relations

Can a non distinct ordered pair in a relation R, belong to its power RR

**Here is the given problem :**

Let R= {(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)}

they have give that 
 RR or RoR = {(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2)}

RR is defined as = { | a   A  c  C   b [b  B    R1    R2 ] } .

I understand the reason of all the ordered pairs in RR except (1,1)

how (1,1) be in RoR,  Your help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $R=\{(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)\}$, then $R^2=\{(1,1),(2,1),\underline{(3,1)},(4,2)\}$. Also, instead of what you wrote for the definition of $R^2$ (of which I can't make much sense), I would define $R^2=\{(a,b)\in R\mid \exists c[(a,c)\in R\land (c,b)\in R]\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aR^2c$. Here $1R1$ and $1R1$ gives $1R^21$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So here 1R1 is implicitly considered to be present twice ?

Comment: Here $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: there is only one 1R1 given in the set of relation, so we can use that as two entites?

Comment: @deepakguna It's a set, multiplicity does not matter. You don't "use up" the entities by stating that $a\mathrel Rb$, it's simply a proposition: $a$ is related to $b$ by $R$ means that the pair $(a,b)$ is an element of $R$. Saying that "$(1,1)$ is an element of $R$ and $(1,1)$ is an element of $R$" is still true regardless of saying the same thing twice.